# How to tail a file with a randomized name?

Tags: command-line, bash, tail

I have a log file that I'd like to `tail -f`. I know which directory the file is in and the name of the file, up to a point. But, I know that there will be a random 9 digits added to the end of the file name.

Can I write a command that always `tail`s that file no matter what the random 9 digit suffix is?

Example:

`tail -f /tmp/logger_output/log_file_i_want_to_read.log123456789`

And the next time, the command is:

`tail -f /tmp/logger_output/log_file_i_want_to_read.log987654321`

etc.

Note: we can assume that file will be the only one with that name `log_file_i_want_to_read.log##########` in that directory.

Comment: Try `tail -f /tmp/logger_output/log_file_i_want_to_read.log*` can't test on phone....

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, depending how specific you need to be about the match.

(matches zero or more trailing characters of any kind):

```
tail -f /tmp/logger_output/log_file_i_want_to_read.log*
```

(matches a trailing string of at least one decimal digit):

```
shopt -s extglob
tail -f /tmp/logger_output/log_file_i_want_to_read.log+([0-9])
```

(matches a trailing string of exactly 9 digits):

```
tail -f /tmp/logger_output/log_file_i_want_to_read.log[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```